# What's the difference between putting std::string and std::string::c_str() into a stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, stream

We're seeing a strange scenario that basically boils down to the following:

```
std::string something = "someval";
std::stringstream s;

s << something;
std::cout << s.str();
```

is not equal to:

```
std::string something = "someval";
std::stringstream s;

s << something.c_str();
std::cout << s.str();
```

Taking that a step farther - the output is not gibberish in either case.  What is happening is the output from case 1 appears to be mapped to another (valid) string in the system whereas the output from case 2 is what is expected.

We see this behavior by simply changing:

```
s << something;
```

To:

```
s << something.c_str();
```

I know this sounds crazy (or it does to me), and I haven't been able to replicate it out of the larger system - so sorry for no "working" example.  But does anyone know how this kind of thing can happen?  Can we be stepping on memory somewhere or doing something to a stringtable in some location or anything else like that?

Comment: Post the real code which shows the difference!

Comment: Does the something string in your actual code contain embedded nul characters?

Comment: If you are corrupting memory or somehow invoking undefined behaviour, then there an almost infinite number of possible causes.  Probably none of them have anything to do with the `stringstream` class, that's just coincidence.

Comment: Yes. `something` or `s` might be ruined. Two things that have caused trouble for me: A. `this` is actually deleted while I'm trying to operate on members, and B. I have unwittingly linked to different variants of the standard library (debug/release, or similar mixup) and I am trying to use a `std::string` created by one implementation as if it were of the other implementation.

Comment: The option 2 doesn't compile in my case: `s << something.c_str()` leads to `error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char *'` (MS Visual Studio 2008, strings included by `#include<string>`)

Comment: What implementation of `std::string` and `std::stringstream` are you using? Just to eliminate the possibility of a copy-on-write bug.

Comment: Honestly, we're working with a proprietary RTOS which has its own implementations for alot of things (supposedly compliant) - but something may be up with it.  Nawaz - its not possible to post the real code for about 15 different reasons or I would have - and I couldn't reproduce it outside the application unfortunately.  Oli - I probably agree with you - the process in question has many threads, a pointer's probably just stepping on something :(  I'll leave it open for a while and see if anyone comes up with an interesting thought then I'll close it later.  Thanks so far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is different if the string contains nul characters, `'\0'`.

The .c_str() version will compute the length up to the nul, while the std::string output will know its length and output all its characters.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I'm aware of these differences though - any chance you know anything about how a literal string "Hello World" would be stored in the program memory when used to initialize a c-string as opposed to a std::string?  That might help alot :)

Comment: There would be no difference there. A std::string constructor would copy from the string literal, as would a `char str[] = ".."`. The output operators would use strlen for a char* and .size() for a std::string. That's about all the difference there is. Unless the data is corrupt somehow...